# Azure Service Bus Session Enabled Subscription Creation through ARM template

Tags: azure, session, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

I was able to create a service bus namespace, topic and subscription using the following example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-resource-manager-namespace-topic-with-rule
I wanted to understand how is it possible to enable sessions on the Subscription while creating the resource through ARM template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `requiresSession` property that can be set to `true` to enable sessions on a subscription.

You can [refer the reference docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.servicebus/2017-04-01/namespaces/topics/subscriptions) for the same.